# Format *.tsx files on save in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, react-tsx

In `settings.json` it is possible to only format `*.ts` files with:

```
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

but I can't get it to work for `*.tsx` files.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
"[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

See also [Language specific editor settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings)

Comment: This doesn't work as of Oct 15 2020, any ideas what has happened?

Comment: Hmm I just checked and it seems to be working for me. Are you missing an update? Do you have it set to false somewhere else? Do you have the formatter disabled?

Comment: Finally got it to work, I needed to run the formatted manually first before it would do it on save. There were conflicting linters trying to lint the same file but it threw no errors. The above snippet needs the explicit setting of which linter you want it to use as well if you have multiple installed.

Comment: Yes, I also faced same problem. To setup default linter open the command palette Ctrl+Shift+P and configure the default formatter.

Comment: To follow-up on @JaskaranSingh, Ctrl-Shift-P, start typing and then select "Format Document", and it'll ask for a default formatter. After that, the "formatOnSave" setting will pick up.

Answer (score 21):

You can install [Prettier Code formatter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) and add these two options in your settings.json file

```
{
  "typescript.format.enable": false,
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked unlike other in my case.

Comment: In my case, it was already added to the settings.json. For it to work with `.tsx` just change `"[typescript]"` to `"[typescriptreact]"`.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I added both in my `settings.json` as I noticed the .ts file is not formatted when I save, here's the updated settings:

```
"[typescript]": { // for .ts files
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
"[typescriptreact]": { // for .tsx files
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": { // apply ESLint
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
},
```

Answer (score 7):

Alternative way with using a plugin like 'ESLint':

```
"[typescriptreact]": {
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
"[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode", /// TSX auto format on save Prettier
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": { /// TSX auto format on save ESLint
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I messed up with keyboard shortcuts.

- Problem faced: ***Format on save was not working.***
- Solution: I opened my keyboard shortcut json file and searched for `cmd+s` and found ther was another shortcut that I created for split right that contained `cmd+s cmd+r`.
- **Summary**: Once I removed keyboard shortcuts started from `cmd+s` from all custom shortcuts that I created. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the only thing that worked was adding `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",` into my `.prettierrc` config file.

Also keep in mind that if the `Prettier: Require Config` is selected, it will use the [prettier config](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html) and will ignore your configs in `.vscode/settings.json`